# How do I delete a cell from tableview

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to delete a cell from a tableview, and from Firestore too.
This how I declared my cart :

```
struct Cart
{
    var photoKeyCart: String
    var foodCart: String
    var priceCart: Int
}

var cart: [Cart] = [] // This is in the cart controller
```

This is my tableview where I have my cart items :

```
extension CartViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var sum = 0
        
        for item in cart{
            sum += item.priceCart
        }
        
        priceTotalLabel.text = "\(sum) lei"
        return cart.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = cartTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell
        let carts = cart[indexPath.row]
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let photoRef = storageRef.child(carts.photoKeyCart)
        
        cell.foodInCartPrice.text = " \(carts.priceCart) lei "
        cell.foodInCartName.text = carts.foodCart
        cell.foodInCartImage.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.foodInCartImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.foodInCartImage.frame.height/2
        cell.foodInCartImage.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return cell
        
    }
```

This is how im getting the data from the Firestore into the cart. This is called in the view did load.

```
func getCartProducts() {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        db.collection("CartDatabase").document(userID).collection("CartItems").getDocuments {  (document, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            } else {
                for document in document!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    let newEntry = Cart(photoKeyCart: data["photoKeyCart"] as! String, foodCart: data["foodCart"] as! String , priceCart: data["priceCart"] as! Int
                    )
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    self.cart.append(newEntry)
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //  self.datas = self.filteredData
                self.cartTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

And, this is how im trying to delete the cell from the tableview, and from the Firestore too.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        let carts = cart[indexPath.row]
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let photoRef = storageRef.child(carts.photoKeyCart)
        
        photoRef.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("File deleted successfully")
            }
        }
        
        
        
     
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        db.collection("CartDatabase").document(userID).collection("CartItems").getDocuments {  (document, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                for document in document!.documents {
                    //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    db.collection("CartDatabase").document(userID).collection("CartItems").document(document.documentID).delete()
                    //self.db.collection("users").document((user?.uid)!).collection("children").document("\(document.documentID)").delete()
                }
            }}
        
        
        
      
        cart.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        
    }
}
```

I have the following problem. When im trying to delete the cell, it works, but when im closing the cart and coming back again to the cart, it deletes all the items into the cart, not just the one I tried to delete.

What I want to achieve : to delete just only the cell selected.
Help :D

**UPDATE:**
I have a tableview with which contains a food, each cell is aa different king of food. I have a plus button, when the plus button is tapped, ill send the datas of the food into the Firestore, and in the cart I retrieve the data.

This is how im sending the data to the cart :

```
    func updateDocument(collection: String, newValueDict: [String : Any], completion:@escaping (Bool) -> Void = {_ in }) {
        
                    
                     let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        db.collection(collection).document(userID).collection("CartItems").document().setData(newValueDict, merge: true){ err in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                            completion(false)
                            
                        }else{
                            
                            completion(true)
                          
                           
                        }
                    }
                     
                 }
```

And when I tapped the cell :

```
cell.didTapButton = {
            
            self.updateDocument(collection: "CartDatabase",newValueDict: ["foodCart" : mancare.foodName, "photoKeyCart": mancare.photoKeyRestaurant, "priceCart": mancare.priceFood])
           
        }
```

**Check the photos**
[Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BcRe.png)
[Photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G2xB.png)

Comment: You don't need `DispatchQueue.main.async {` in Firebase closures. UI calls are always done on the main thread; networking is done on a background thread. Why are you getting documents from Firebase to then just delete them? That's a lot of wasted bandwidth.

Comment: So , that s the problem @Jay?

Comment: No. See my updated comment.

Comment: I think there's a overall design issue; when reading data from Firebase, each document will have a documentId - that should be a property of the Cart object as well as the CartItems. When a user deletes a cartItem, you'll know which row they choose to delete and can then get that object from your dataSource. Then you'll have the documentId and can remove it from the array (by index) and also remove it from Firebase by that documentId.

Comment: @Jay, thank you Jay for your response. Im home now and i can try somethin else to make it work. So i need to add to my cart struct a documentId and in the firebase too in the CartItems? After that, what do i need to change to my code?

Comment: See my above comment(s). It's unclear why you get documents to then just delete them. Once you have the documentId, you can delete the document directly using the process I described above.

Comment: @Jay I updated the post, check it out how im sending the data to the cart

Comment: Your question title says *How do I delete a cell from tableview* and it looks like your comments and updated code have to do with writing data. Please stay on one topic, which is the original question about deleting. If you have another question about a different topic, post it separately.

Comment: @Jay that's my question, im having data into my cart, and I want to delete them by swiping, but in Firestore too, because, but when I'm trying to delete one cell, it deletes all the documents, not just one.

Comment: All of the code in the Edit part of your question ADDS data to Firebase. You asked how to remove it. My above comment says how to do that; when the user swipes a row, get that corresponding object from your datasource (array). Read the documentId from that object and then remove the object from the array and delete it from Firebase (using that documentId). See the guide [Delete Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) for the code to use to delete data at a reference.

Comment: Also, I will mention this again; the code in the top part of the question `.collection("CartItems").getDocuments` gets all of the documents and then deletes them `.collection("CartItems").document(document.documentID).delete()`. Not sure why you're doing that.

Comment: @Jay I saw something similar to my questions on stackoverflow, that s why I  have done that " get.documents " . I have deleted that, and added only the method. ` db.collection("CartDatabase").document(userID).collection("CartItems").document().delete().  { err in ` . But I don't know how to accomplish this, "  **when the user swipes a row, get that corresponding object from your datasource (array). Read the documentId from that object and then remove the object from the array and delete it from Firebase (using that documentId)** ". Now when im swiping, it doesn't delete nothing from the databa

Comment: I have taken the steps I outlined above, and then from above that, and put them in an answer:. Step 1) when the user swipes a row, get that corresponding object from your datasource (array). Step 2) remove the object from the array and then Step 3) delete it from Firebase (using that documentId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of the code it's hard to provide a specific example but let me cover this at a high level.

Suppose we have a posts class object

```
class PostsClass {
   var docId = ""
   var post = ""
}
```

and an class array (aka a 'dataSource') to store them in

```
var postsArray = [PostsClass]()
```

The first step is to load all of the posts from Firebase, storing the docId and post text in each class and then store the class in the dataSource array.

```
myFirebase.getDocuments { doc...
   for doc in documents { //iterate over the documents and populate the array
      let post = PostClass(populate with data from firebase)
      self.postsArray.add(post)
   }
}
```

the dataSouce array will look like this

```
postsArray[0] = some post
postsArray[1] = another post
```

etc, and all of that is displayed in a tableView.

The user then decides to delete the post at row 1. So they swipe row one, which fires a tableView delegate event letting the app know the index of the swiped row.

Step 1: You then get that post from the array based on the swiped row index

```
let postToDelete = self.postsArray[swiped index]
let docIdToDelete = postsToDelete.docID
```

Step 2: then remove it from the array

```
self.postsArray.deleteRow(atIndex: swiped index)
```

Step 3: then delete it from Firebase.

```
self.my_firebase.collection("posts").document(docIdToDelete).delete {....
```

Note that the `func tableView:tableView:commit editingStyle` will present the editing style of `.delete` when the row is supposed to be deleted and also provide the index in `indexPath.row`